# having an array that can be accessed from all viewControllers

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

i have a root view controller that has a container view embedded that links to my TabBarController and 4 different tab views. The root view controller is embed in a Navigation Controller as i have a couple of buttons that allow for measurement changes and a geographical location selection.

Rather than each tab loading the same data each time(as current), i wish to load the data into arrays via the root view controller and then access these 4 NSMutableArrays from each of the 4 tabs. what would be the more efficient and correct practice way to do this?  I also have a timer setup in the root controller so these NSMutableArrays update with extra data anywhere from 5 seconds to 5 minutes, user set as loading live weather information.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are not exactly something I'd recommend as a design pattern, but if you feel it's necessary for each controller to have this data, the best approach would be a singleton.

Imagine that the data in question is an array of co-ordinates. If I **had** to give multiple objects access to this data, I would probably implement it in this way:

- I would create a class which manages the data. In this case, I would call it LocationDataManager.
- On this class, I would create a class method which return a shared instance of the class.

-

```
/**
 *  Returns a shared instance of this class.
 *
 *  @return A singleton instance of this class.
 */
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static LocationDataManager *sharedInstance;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken,
    ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Obviously you would need to declare the method in the public interface in the .h file:

```
/**
 *  Returns a shared instance of this class.
 *
 *  @return A singleton instance of this class.
 */
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
```

- I would then add a property to this class with all of the data. I would declare it in the public interface as read only:

-

```
/** An array of the location data.  */
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *locations;
```

In the implementation I would use the getter method to return the necessary data:

```
- (NSArray *)locations
{
    return @[coordinateA, coordinateB, coordinateC];
}
```